# Java multi-"where" keyword?

Tags: java, generics, where-clause, keyword

How can I limit 2 generic types in a class definition? How should I "where T : " 2 times?
I have 2 interfaces Simplex and Complex, and I want a class like

```
public class MyClass<T,S> where T: Simplex, where S: Complex
{
...
}
```

? or am I doing it wrong? Where can I find this documentation? googling for "java keyword where generics" doesnt really help: where is a very common word... I cant find it in the java trail on generics either...

Comment: `where` is not a java keyword

Comment: in java we say: class MyClass<T extends Simplex, S extends Complex>

Comment: What you posted is C# syntax.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe this is the syntax you're looking for:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Simplex, S extends Complex> { }
```

See [this Java Tutorials page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

In Java you can use bounded type parameters:

```
public class MyClass<T extends Simplex, S extends Complex>
```

Comment: If I can nitpick, these aren't wildcards - they're type parameters.